# [syntax-error], unexpected tag on line 1

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I believe the [syntax-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-error) conflicts with this close reason:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

It is my opinion that the existence of this tag encourages newbie users (who wouldn't otherwise be able to create tags) that syntax errors are acceptable questions.

While it is possible that a syntax error could make for an interesting question (in particularly obscure cases), overall I don't think it's worth being a tag.

Furthermore, considering the fact that syntax varies astoundingly with the language, what may be valid in one would be totally wrong in another, making it difficult to be an expert in syntax errors specifically. And if you were an expert syntax error finder, you might be better off on Code Review or something to put your code analysing abilities to good use ^_^

So... this is my first burninate request, I hope I don't get burninated instead :D

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vrryL.png

Comment: @BoltClock Is it hot here or is it just me?

Comment: It will be tough. Burninating this tag will mean closing most of the questions that have it (they are probably off-topic). But I think it is worth it.

Comment: Relatedly, what about the 6k or so questions with the [tag:compiler-errors] tag?

Comment: The tags tag on a tagged question on tagging of tagged questions was removed.

Comment: [Some user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/272735/user272735?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=1) is adding this tag to quite a number of questions, not sure if that's a good or a bad thing.

Comment: @BoltClock _*flags comment as offensive*_

Answer (score 44):

Not all syntax errors are as simple as it seems.

Take a look at the [top five syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-error?sort=votes&pageSize=50) questions, should the tag be removed from them? The answers for these questions illustrate peculiarities with particular parsers, idiosyncrasies with particular libraries and gotchas with character encodings.

So while I hate basic syntax error questions the same as everyone else, we don't need to eliminate the tag because it is still possible to generate good questions *about* syntax errors - the crappy questions *because* of syntax errors can still be closed.

Comment: +1: Spot on; last paragraph clinches it.

Comment: Is there any value in being able to search for [tag:syntax-error] questions, though? Because that's what the existence of a tag should really be judged on, not whether good questions are possible.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If meta-tags were used to *classify*, but were only allowed in combination with "real" tags, both for tagging a question and for searching, then it would have value. That's not the world we live in, though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I'd say there is value. If nothing else, this is a way to find questions that need editing (maybe just removing the tag) or closing. In other words, it serves as a kind of low-quality review queue. (I'm sure this comment serves as both a reason to keep the tag and a reason to eliminate it. ;)